# How to subclass UINavigationBar to work with Three20/iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, three20, uinavigationbar

Many of you have probably noticed that we cant anymore create a category to override `UINavigationBar` `drawRect` in iOS5. Now actually I don't see a good way of implementing this customization without using a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and set it inside a navigationController->navigationBar in my MainWindow.xib. However, TTNavigator do not recognize that `navigationController` since every `TTViewController` has their own superclass of `TTNavigationController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to solve it for Three20 but in general for supporting IOS 5 you can use this method

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];

if([navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
    [navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
} 
else{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [imgView setTag:TOOLBAR_TAG];
    [navigationBar insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: i put this code in an helper function and i call it in my application delegate method `code`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: thanks, I just got it solved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772382/what-should-i-do-to-adapt-my-app-to-ios-5-0-keeping-compatibility-with-ios-4/7772647#7772647

Comment: which is somehow the same way you said but I use [UINavigationBar appearance] at application delegate, but actually I dont know how to do deal with devices below iOS5, since they not provide appearance

Comment: leave the drawRect: in the appDelegate which sets the navigation image, iOS5 won't call it, but everything below it will.